# How to add 'auto_increment' to another column besides 'id' in rails table defination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, auto-increment

If I need to add 'auto_increment' to a new column called 'another_id' in a table, how can I make it?
Is there an option like:

---

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.integer :another_id, :auto_increment => true # Is there a option like this?
  ...

  t.timestamps
end
```

---

In development env I use sqlite3, and mysql in production env;

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: In development env I use sqlite3, and mysql in production env;

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the rails api for create_table has a autoincrement option.  in the up method after the create_table you might have to execute a ALTER TABLE sql command to set the column to autoincrement.  Note that this could be different for database vendors.

syntax is something like: execute "ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col_name AUTO INCREMENT"

or you could just run the execute command in the up method to create the table using a sql create table statement.